# reverte a change that was made in a file in a remote branch to be able to pull from main

Tags: git, repository

by mistake I made a change in file in my remote branch but now I need to pull from main with
`git pull --main`
and I dont want to commit this change but to go back the previous version and pull. How could I do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The specific command `git pull --main` makes no sense, and in general your overall question indicates that you need a good tutorial on what Git is and does, how it does it, and how to use it. You might want to be more specific about exactly which commands you ran (e.g., when did you run `git commit`, did you use `git switch` or `git checkout` and if so when, and so on).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! it is more likely that my question was not clear, sorry for that. So I need to pull from the main to synchronise some changes that my colleague did on my branch after I made a pull request, but my mistake I myself change a file before pulling her changes and now I can't pull from the main if I don't commit my change. Simce I don't want to commit this change, I wanted to know if I can reverte the change I made to the file to avoid making a useless commit.

Comment: You *can* use `git revert`, but this *adds another commit*. Your existing commit remains committed. You *can* kick one or more commits "off the end" of a branch using `git reset`; be *very* careful with this. If you haven't *committed* something yet, you can use `git restore` (in Git 2.23 or later; there are similar commands in older Git versions) to discard your uncommitted work. Be careful with these: there's no getting it back!

Comment: It's still not entirely clear to me which of these might be right for your case, but `git restore` sounds the most likely. Remember that files that are in your *working tree* are not actually *in* Git at all: they get copied in and out with various other Git commands, but while you're working on them, they're just ordinary files.